# Understanding .NET Core HttpClient.GetStringAsync

Tags: .net, httpclient

I want to understand what the following code is doing (it's from a tutorial):

```
        string token = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("example-data/token.json");
```

My understanding is that _httpclient is used to call a Uri. Is this code making a network trip at all? What is the Uri here? What is returned?

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient can be initialized with a [BaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?view=net-7.0), after which any URLs supplied to the various GetBlah methods can be relative to that (which is what appears to be the case here). [GetStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh551746(v=vs.118)) will return the response as a string.

Comment: So the base address is set like this: ```new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });``` so it is "/". What does that resolve to for HttpClient?